# make a vertical scroll view with horizontal rows react native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to programming and react-native and I'm trying to make a `Scrollview` and get values from a JSON file and show 2 boxes in each row but when I use `flexDirection : 'row'` they all merge into each other.

Thank you I appreciate every help.
The section below is my code:

```
export default class Creative extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isLoading: true, refreshing: false, }
    }

    _fetchData = () => {
        const key = 'D0BEFCE031A955294DE1DD87C14B13EA77CBF8A86F293FD30E9B8D57F3C401F9';
        var type = 'creative';
        const lal = `imapp=${key}&type=${type}`;
        fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', {
            method: 'get',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.list,
                    refreshing: false,
                });

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._fetchData();
    }

    _onRefresh = () => {
        () => this.setState({ refreshing: true, });
        status = '1';
        this._fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#323232' }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
                        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.dataSource}
                                renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>}
                                keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Try ```numColumns``` in Flatlist.

Comment: @SDushan i wanted to but it doesn't work, it doesn't show anything

Comment: Could you share your source code

Comment: @SDushan the whole page?

Comment: yes if you could

Comment: @SDushan i've changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numColumns` in ReactNative Flatlist to render multiple columns & Change your `Flatlist` as below

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.dataSource}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{ width: '40%', justifyContent: 'space-between', backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 5 }}>
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
        </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    numColumns={2}
/>
```

Change this according to your requirements.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it still not working, theres nothing on the page

Comment: @imcouri change ```dataSource: responseJson.list``` to ```dataSource: responseJson.movies```.